# Analizer to ignore accents and plural singular in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am working on ignoring accents and plural/singular when I make a search query. I copied the Spanish analyzer from here and left only the stemmer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html

you can check my code in Python (I bulk the data from a CSV latter):

```
settings={
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "spanish_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "light_spanish"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt_spanish": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "spanish_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
    
es.indices.create(index="activities", body=settings)
```

However, when I try a GET query from insomnia like `geometrico`, `geométrico`, `geométricos`, `geometricos` I get 0 results and there is a doc with Title `Cuerpos geométricos`. It should match since I want to make no difference with accents and plural singular. Any ideas?

The GET query I do:

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "geométricos",
                    "fields": [
                        "Descripcion",
                        "Nombre",
                        "Tags"
                    ],
                 "analyzer":"rebuilt_spanish"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I found my error. In case is useful for somebody, I had to add "analyzer":"rebuilt_spanish" in descripcion, nombre, tags in the mapping

Comment: You are using `rebuilt_spanish` analyzer in search query. What is the definition of this analyzer?

Comment: In the first code area.

Comment: What is the mapping for the following fields: `Descripcion`, `Nombre`, `Tags`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `ASCII folding token filter` to your token filters check official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html). So your `Analyzer` should be like this:

**Anlayzer:**

```
"analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "spanish_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "light_spanish"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt_spanish": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding", // ASCII folding token filter
            "lowercase",
            "spanish_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not really, spanish_stemmer already handles accents. My error was not adding the analyzer in the mapping but thanks